# Determine whether the following function is continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Determine whether the following function is continuous at $(0,0)$:
>   $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{xy}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}} & \text{if $(x,y)$ $\neq(0,0)$} \\
> 1 & \text{if $(x,y)=(0,0)$}  \\
> \end{cases}$$

---

Here's what I did. I know that $f(0,0)=1$ and I think that I have to show either $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y) = f(0,0) \ \text{or} \neq f(0,0)$$

How should I go about this?

Comment: Do you mean $f(0, 0) = 0$, by chance?

Comment: An easy way to go about this question is converting to polar coordinates.

Comment: T. Bongers, I think $f(0,0)=1$ by the bottom case

Comment: @user95087: what T. Bongers means is that if you have $f(0,0)=1$, then this function is not continuous. But if you have $f(0,0)=0$, then it will be continuous.

Comment: @user95087 Approaching along any of the lines $y = 0$, $x = 0$, $y = \pm x$ leads to $0$ at the origin. As stated, it's discontinuous for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at $x=0$ and $y\to 0$ which gives you $0$ as limit.
Or look at $x=y$

Comment: No typo, the bottom case is correctly stated...

Answer (score 1):

For continuity at $(0,0)$ you need the limit to exist and to agree with the value of the function.

If you really have $f(0,0)=1$, then it is easy to see that the function is not continuous, because the limit---if it exists---will have to be zero. This can be seen as suggested by Dominic, by using lines.

Now the limit at $(0,0)$ does exist. A hint for that is that the numerator in the fraction has degree two, while the denominator has degree one. To use this idea, fix $\varepsilon>0$. If $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\varepsilon$, then 
$$
\frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\varepsilon.
$$
As $\varepsilon $ is arbitrary, this shows that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=0.
$$
In other words, the function has a removable discontinuity at $(0,0)$.